# sleep and only after that run a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I want my pc to wait for 5 seconds and then run a script

```
sleep 5 | python3 resource.py
```

What happens - script is executed and after that comes the delay.

How can a properly wait/delay 5 second before my script is executed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `;` to sequence the commands, or add them as separate lines:

```
sleep 5; python3 resource.py
```

or

```
sleep 5
python3 resource.py
```

Using a pipe starts both sides of the pipe simultaneously.

Comment: Or `sleep 5 && python3 resource.py` which will ensure that the Python script is _not_ run if the `sleep` is killed.

Comment: ... Actually, I think a pipe starts the right side *first* to make sure it has a `stdin` pipe to redirect into.

Comment: @Shadur no, the pipe can exist without there being a receiving process; try `(date +%s.%N > f1) | (date +%s.%N > f2)` — the timestamp in `f2` will usually be later than the one in `f1`.